# vba format function incorrectly interpreting number as date

Tags: vba, ms-access

Why does VBA interpret "093 0005" as a date?

In MS Access VBA, the following line:
Format("093 0005", "0000000000000") returns "0000000034090"

34090 is the vba numeric equivalent of the date 5/1/1993.

In most cases this kind of date assumption does not occur.  For example:

Format("092 0250", "0000000000000") returns "092 0250", i.e. does not try to apply formatting.

Format("0930005", "0000000000000") returns "0000000930005" as expected.

The only solution to this that I have come up with so far is to code around using this function when the inbound string contains a space or use the IsDate function.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Access per se. In any VBA, the format function will behave like this if the text is either separated by a `SPACE`, `HYPHEN`, or a `DASH`. So this

```
Debug.Print Format("093 0005", "0000000000000") 
Debug.Print Format("093/0005", "0000000000000") 
Debug.Print Format("093-0005", "0000000000000")
```

will return `0000000034090`

It will try and convert it to **date** or a **number** and if it is a valid date or number then it will show you the numeric equivalent of it. And if it is not a date or number equivalent then it will leave it as it is. I believe the reason for this is that the `Format` function is unable to ascertain the "Format" of the value and takes it as a string. It is similar to then saying `Format("Blah", "0000000000000")`. It is but obvious that you will not expect `Format` function to format it as `000000000blah`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any article in MS knowledge-base which explains why Format function behaves like this.

The only way that I have discovered in the past to get around it is to use the `VAL` function to convert it to a number. So

```
Debug.Print Format(Val("093 0005"), "0000000000000")
```

will give you the desired result `0000000930005`

However if the numbers are separated by a `HYPHEN` or a `DASH` then the `VAL` function is useless. For that you will have to use `REPLACE` to replace the `HYPHEN` or a `DASH` with `SPACE`. However I doubt that you will be formatting numbers which have a `HYPHEN` or a `DASH`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I guess what surprised me was that the function interprets numbers as dates when the requested format is not date-like.  Your solution does work in my case.  I am also able to use: De

Comment: Rick when you type `?Format(Val("093 0005"), "0000000000000")` in the Immediate Window what do you get?

Comment: Ok What is the regional settings on your pc?